# How do I make ray.tune.run reproducible?

Tags: python-3.x, ray, ray-tune

I'm using Tune [class-based Trainable API](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/_modules/ray/tune/trainable.html). See code sample:

```py
from ray import tune
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
# first run
tune.run(tune.Trainable, ...)
# second run, expecting same result
np.random.seed(42)
tune.run(tune.Trainable, ...)
```

The problem is that `tune.run` results are still different, likely reason being that each ray actor still has different seed.

**Question**: how do I make `ray.tune.run` reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

(This answer focuses on class API and ray version 0.8.7. Function API does not support reproducibility due to implementation specifics)

There are two main sources of undeterministic results.

**1. Search algorithm**

Every [search algorithm](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/api_docs/suggestion.html) supports random seed, although interface to it may vary. This initializes hyperparameter space sampling.

For example, if you're using [`AxSearch`](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/api_docs/suggestion.html#ax-tune-suggest-ax-axsearch), it looks like this:

```py
from ax.service.ax_client import AxClient
from ray.tune.suggest.ax import AxSearch

client = AxClient(..., random_seed=42)
client.create_experiment(...)
algo = AxSearch(client)
```

**2. Trainable API**

This is distributed among worker processes, which requires seeding within [`tune.Trainable`](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/_modules/ray/tune/trainable.html) class. Depending on the `tune.Trainable.train` logic that you implement, you need to manually seed `numpy`, `tf`, or whatever other framework you use, inside `tune.Trainable.setup` by passing seed with `config` argument of `tune.run`.

The following code is based on [RLLib PR5197](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/5197/files) that handled the same issue:

See the example:

```py
from ray import tune
import numpy as np
import random

class Tuner(tune.Trainable):
  def setup(self, config):
    seed = config['seed']
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    ...
  ...

seed = 42

tune.run(Tuner, config={'seed': seed})
```

Comment: I am using the functional API, and still unable to reproduce the results. Before calling 

     tune.run(...)

I am using random.seed(...) np.random.seed(...).

Comment: @Roxana you need to do `random.seed(...)` inside the function, doing it before tune.run won't suffice. The function gets distributed among workers, so put the initialization logic inside.

Comment: HI @ptyshevs, the problem I am having is not during training (given the same configs I get the same results), but with the configs themselves. If I run my code multiple times, the configs obtained are different. I can share a code that you can use to test what I am saying...

Comment: Hi @ptyshevs, if you would like to take a look, I have asked in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617962/obtaining-different-set-of-configs-across-multiple-calls-in-ray-tune.