# Obtaining different set of configs across multiple calls in ray tune

Tags: ray, ray-tune

I am trying to make my code reproducible. I have already added np.random.seed(...) and random.seed(...), and at the moment I am not using pytorch or tf, therefore no scheduler or searcher can introduce any random issue. The set of configs produced with the above code should be always the same across multiple calls. However, it is not the case.

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you!

Here the code:

```py
import ray
from ray import tune
import random
import numpy as np

def training_function(config, data_init):
    print('CONFIG:', config)
    tune.report(end_of_training=1, acc=0, f=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ray.init(num_cpus=12)
    tune_config = {'sentence_classification': False, 
              'norm_word_emb': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_crf': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_char': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'word_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'char_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'seed_num': 1267}
    data = {'a': 1}
    tune_seed = tune_config['seed_num']
    random.seed(tune_seed)
    np.random.seed(tune_seed)
    n_samples = 15
    exp_name = 'experiment_name'
    analysis = tune.run(
        tune.with_parameters(training_function, data_init={'data': data}),
        name=exp_name,
        metric="f",
        mode="max",
        queue_trials=True,
        config=tune_config,
        num_samples=n_samples,
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 1},
        checkpoint_at_end=True,
        max_failures=0,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Function-level API cannot be made reproducible (ray v1.1.0, may be subject to change).

#### Wait, but why

1. `tune.run` creates an [`Experiment`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f73014291bf1ccacb058bdb7399d5da0e38d81e/python/ray/tune/tune.py#L313) object, passing your function there.
2. `Experiment` [registers](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f73014291bf1ccacb058bdb7399d5da0e38d81e/python/ray/tune/experiment.py#L276) the function as trainable by calling `register_trainable`
3. `register_trainable` wraps your function using [`wrap_function`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f73014291bf1ccacb058bdb7399d5da0e38d81e/python/ray/tune/registry.py#L62)
4. `wrap_function` will create a class-level API (ray Actor) by inheriting from [`FunctionRunner`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f73014291bf1ccacb058bdb7399d5da0e38d81e/python/ray/tune/function_runner.py#L255) class.
5. `FunctionRunner` doesn't have any callback access into `setup` method.

The way `Actor` works is, oversimplifying, it gets distributed among workers and then initialized in different processes using `setup` method. This is why it is crutial to pass seed and implement initialization logic inside your custom `Trainable`, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498866/9632441) answer. Seeding is needed because `tune.choice` is just a wrapper around `random`/`np.random` functions. You can observe this in [`tune/sample.py`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f73014291bf1ccacb058bdb7399d5da0e38d81e/python/ray/tune/sample.py).

See the example:

```py
import ray
from ray import tune
import random
import numpy as np

class Tunable(tune.Trainable):
    def setup(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.seed = config['seed_num']
        random.seed(self.seed)
        np.random.seed(self.seed)
    
    def step(self):
        print('CONFIG:', self.config)
        return {tune.result.DONE: 'done', 'acc': 0, 'f': 0}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ray.init(num_cpus=12)
    tune_config = {'sentence_classification': False, 
              'norm_word_emb': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_crf': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_char': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'word_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'char_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'seed_num': 1267}
    data = {'a': 1}
    tune_seed = tune_config['seed_num']
    n_samples = 15
    exp_name = 'experiment_name'
    analysis = tune.run(
        Tunable,
        name=exp_name,
        metric="f",
        mode="max",
        queue_trials=True,
        config=tune_config,
        num_samples=n_samples,
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 1},
        checkpoint_at_end=False,
        max_failures=0,
    )
```

Comment: Hi @ptyshevs, unfortunately, this does not solves my problem either. Notice that I am not trying to control the randomness during training, but during the config(s) generated.
Two runs of this code generates different configurations (not just different orders of the configs, but different set of values).

Comment: I seems like a bug in Ray and a ticket has been raised: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/13295

Comment: I wonder if this is related only to categorical variable (tune.choice), since other things are using numpy.random module

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing the behavior where the seeding works. I ran this script:

```py
import ray
from ray import tune
import numpy as np
import random


def training_function(config, data_init):
    print('CONFIG:', config)
    tune.report(end_of_training=1, acc=0, f=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ray.init(num_cpus=12)
    tune_config = {'sentence_classification': False, 
              'norm_word_emb': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_crf': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'use_char': tune.choice(['True', 'False']), 
              'word_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'char_seq_feature': tune.choice(['CNN', 'LSTM', 'GRU']), 
              'seed': 1267}
    data = {'a': 1}
    tune_seed = tune_config['seed']
    random.seed(tune_seed)
    np.random.seed(tune_seed)
    n_samples = 15
    analysis = tune.run(
        tune.with_parameters(training_function, data_init={'data': data}),
        #name=exp_name,
        metric="f",
        mode="max",
        queue_trials=True,
        config=tune_config,
        num_samples=n_samples,
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 1},
        verbose=2,
        max_failures=0,
    )
```

where I ran one run:

```
Resources requested: 0/16 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs, 0.0/27.0 GiB heap, 0.0/9.28 GiB objects
Current best trial: 84b84_00014 with f=0 and parameters={'sentence_classification': False, 'norm_word_emb': 'False', 'use_crf': 'True', 'use_char': 'False', 'word_seq_feature': 'LSTM', 'char_seq_feature': 'GRU', 'seed': 1267}
Number of trials: 15/15 (15 TERMINATED)
+--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
| Trial name         | status     | loc   | char_seq_feature   | norm_word_emb   | use_char   | use_crf   | word_seq_feature   |   iter |   total time (s) |   end_of_training |   acc |   f |
|--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----|
| _inner_84b84_00000 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | False     | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00149202 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00001 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | True       | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.0014801  |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00002 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | True      | GRU                |      1 |       0.00152397 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00003 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | False     | GRU                |      1 |       0.00165081 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00004 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | False      | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00173998 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00005 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00219083 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00006 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | True            | False      | False     | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00192428 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00007 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00208902 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00008 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | GRU                |      1 |       0.00146484 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00009 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | False      | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00152087 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00010 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | False           | True       | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00124121 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00011 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00124812 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00012 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00133514 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00013 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00142407 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00014 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | True      | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00120211 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
+--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
```

and the subsequent run:

```
Current best trial: 84b84_00014 with f=0 and parameters={'sentence_classification': False, 'norm_word_emb': 'False', 'use_crf': 'True', 'use_char': 'False', 'word_seq_feature': 'LSTM', 'char_seq_feature': 'GRU', 'seed': 1267}
Result logdir: /Users/rliaw/ray_results/_inner_2021-01-07_10-45-31
Number of trials: 15/15 (15 TERMINATED)
+--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
| Trial name         | status     | loc   | char_seq_feature   | norm_word_emb   | use_char   | use_crf   | word_seq_feature   |   iter |   total time (s) |   end_of_training |   acc |   f |
|--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----|
| _inner_84b84_00000 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | False     | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00149202 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00001 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | True       | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.0014801  |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00002 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | True      | GRU                |      1 |       0.00152397 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00003 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | False     | GRU                |      1 |       0.00165081 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00004 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | False      | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00173998 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00005 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00219083 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00006 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | True            | False      | False     | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00192428 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00007 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00208902 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00008 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | GRU                |      1 |       0.00146484 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00009 | TERMINATED |       | CNN                | False           | False      | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00152087 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00010 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | False           | True       | False     | CNN                |      1 |       0.00124121 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00011 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00124812 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00012 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | True       | True      | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00133514 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00013 | TERMINATED |       | LSTM               | True            | False      | True      | CNN                |      1 |       0.00142407 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
| _inner_84b84_00014 | TERMINATED |       | GRU                | False           | False      | True      | LSTM               |      1 |       0.00120211 |                 1 |     0 |   0 |
+--------------------+------------+-------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
```

Notice that the trials and their configs are exactly the same (in the same order).

Comment: If you execute with less number of cpus than 15, or if you stress the system with other processes, (so, the tasks are queued, etc.), and you execute the script multiple times, then  you can see set of configs is not consistent. I have verified it is not just the order that changes.